# Is it possible to define local static variable which is visible only by two functions?

Tags: c, scope, static

I would like to know if C language allows one to define a local static variable which is intended to be used only by 2 functions. So other functions won't be able to see/use this variable.

For example:

```
int f1(){
    static int i = 0;
    // some instructions here
    i = 10;
    // rest of code
}

int f2(){
    i = 0;  // must be the same i variable in f1 function.
    // rest of code
}
```

Is there any way to tell C compiler that `i` variable of `f2` is the same as `f2` `i` variable?

Comment: You could put these functions and the static variable in their own file.

Comment: The only way to do this is in C is to declare the variable with global scope. Furthermore, encapsulation is weak in C, so there is no way to hide this variable from other functions. A good convention to mark this variable as hidden (usually for documentation and code style purposes), is to prefix the variable name with an underscore. In your example it would be `_i`.

Comment: yes. A static variable at file scope will be visible only to the functions in the file

Comment: `gnu-c` (if you use the gcc) also offers nested functions, but that has some peculiarities: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html However, it would enable them to access the local variables of the other function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really. You would have to basically inform the second function of the address of the variable, and dereference it from there, such that they're both using the same memory address.

Alternatively, break those two function out into their own *file* where `static` works a little differently<sup>(a)</sup>:

```
static int i = 0;

int f1(){
    // some instructions here
    i = 10;
    // rest of code
}

int f2(){
    i = 0;  // must be the same i variale in f1 function.
    // rest of code
}
```

No-one outside that file will be able to get at `i`, but you'd probably want a better name for it :-)

---

<sup>(a)</sup> In layman's terms, *within* a function, it really just controls the variable lifetime rather than what can access it (only the function itself can access it). The lifetime allows it to live beyond the end of the function, having the same value the next time you re-enter that function.

*Outside* of a function, `static` doesn't affect the lifetime, only what can access it (nothing outside the file can get to it).

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't understand the superscript (a). Particularly, this line _"What can see it"_.

Comment: @Lucas, I was just explaining the subtle differences with `static` used inside and outside a function. I've re-written it to hopefully be clearer.

Comment: Thanks @paxdiablo for re-writing your answer. Please confirm, if I got you:-
_If a `static` variable is defined `locally`, the `static` class will make the variable's value persist between different function calls, but it'll not be accessible outside the function where it is declared_

Comment: and _If a `static` variable is defined `globally` in a file, it's lifetime and scope will be for all the functions within the file but not outside the file, **even if we include that file**_.

Comment: @Lucas: not *quite.* The accessibility of items is within a translation unit (I used file as a simplification). If any file does an `#include` of the file containing the definition of a variable, it incorporates the included file into its translation unit. So, if you just removed that bold bit, you'd be pretty accurate.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks again. @paxdiablo